# can not select the text after using pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to create some effects using pseudo elements in my page

The problem is I am not able to select the text of real element, how to solve this problem.

following is my code([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a8Mh/)):

**Currently works on Chrome but not firefox**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrp">
    <div class="viscu">Can't Select</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.viscu{text-align:Center;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#0569B6;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #96FAFF;
    padding:5px;
}
.viscu:before{
    border:1px dashed #89EDFC;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-left:1px;}
.viscu:after{
    border:1px dashed #2286D3;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;}
.viscu:before,.viscu:after{
 position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;}
.wrp{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:5%;
    background-color:#9CF;
    padding:20px;}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a8Mh/)
I have tried using Z-index concept, but no luck.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, You mean like `text select`? I am able to on Chrome.

Comment: It's working fine here on Chrome for Windows

Comment: I am using firefox on ubuntu, not able to select the text...

Comment: Including FF for windows too, I'm unable to select text; should update the question just in case!

Comment: @MackieeE you can select the text on chrome but not able to select on firefox on ubuntu

Comment: Works on IE9 not in Firefox Windows7

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need `z-index` but to make it work need an extra tag:

```
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="viscu"><span>Can't Select</span></div>
</div>
```

And In CSS:

```
.viscu span {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1
}
```

Check this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a8Mh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo elements simply cover the text, to make them selectable you just need to add the following.

```
.viscu:before,
.viscu:after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: You could note the [Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) of that property

Comment: @Danko My apologies, I just meant to illustrate the actual problem,